# Do non-spontaneous processes require human intervention?

Tags: thermodynamics

Question: **Do non-spontaneous processes require human intervention? If not, can you give a non-biological example?**

An example of a non-spontaneous process (one that *does* involve intervention) that I have in mind is the electrolysis of water.  That's a thermodynamically uphill (or unfavorable) reaction, with $\Delta G > 0$.  **By my understanding, that's all that is meant by "non-spontaneous."**  It requires the application of non-pV work to make it go in that direction.  In this case, that work is done by setting up an electrolytic cell with a battery to force the reaction. Clearly, there is human intervention involved here.  And there will always be such intervention required for examples given in textbooks, because they are geared toward experiments you can perform in a lab.

This ties in with the everyday meaning of *spontaneous*, i.e. that it doesn't require any intervention.  It just happens on its own.  I've also seen spontaneous processes referred to as **"natural"**, which seems to imply that there's something unnatural about non-spontaneous processes.  As if they required some agent to bring them about.

But again, my understanding is that the 2nd Law says nothing about which processes occur naturally as opposed to requiring an intelligent agent to make them happen.  It merely says that some processes require an input of work to the system, while others do not, and could do work on their surroundings if constraints allowed for it.

I've noticed that ID/creationists exploit this ambiguity in the term *spontaneous* to make it sound like non-spontaneous processes **simply do not occur** in nature.  Because after all, thermodynamically uphill is not the "natural" direction.

I really doubt that, given all the dynamic things happening at the Earth's surface, where one downhill process drives an uphill process.  Such as the huge electric potential generated in a thunderstorm when larger ice particles fall and smack into small ice particles being lifted in the updraft, resulting in lightning.  I don't think of the generation of electric potentials as being particularly "spontaneous", but I also don't know if the Gibbs free energy function really applies to this case.  In this example and others I can think of (such as generation of wind and water power), it is **exergy** that is increasing, i.e. available work.  I would tend to think of a process that increases the exergy of a system as non-spontaneous, but I don't know if it is used that way by physicists.

Comment: Hi @ether, Welcome to PSE. Maybe try focussing your question a bit more, because as it is - it's not clear what you're asking. Can you add a few examples as to what processes you have in mind, and what kind of human intervention you mean?

Comment: Hi @SuperCiocia.  Thank you, I have expanded on my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important distinction is that, in order for a non-spontaneous process to occur, there has to be energy input to the system. So, in your example, the system is just the electrolytic cell; in order for electrolysis to occur, energy must enter the system from outside, e.g. the battery. If you were to consider the cell and the battery as your system, then it would be a spontaneous process.

The question of intelligent agents is irrelevant. Intelligent or not, we still must obey the 2nd law. Consider the edge cases: for your example, what if humans created a machine that automatically does electrolysis? What if someone accidentally knocks a battery into a bowl of salt water and electrolysis occurs? What if an animal did that? You can even concoct a purely natural example of electrolysis occurring- what if lightning strikes the ocean in just the right way?

If you want an example of a non-spontaneous process that's common, consider cloud formation. For clouds to spontaneously form, the temperature profile in the atmosphere has to be such that air that starts rising will, even though it cools as it rises since it's expanding, remain warmer than its new surrounding air. Then, since it's warmer, it will continue to rise until it cools enough to condense into a cloud (and probably past that). But what if the temperature profile is different, so a rising air parcel is cooler than its surrounding air? Then it would go back to where it started. So, this is a non-spontaneous process because energy has to be put into the system to make the air rise. This happens when, for example, the whole region of air moves over a mountain range. Then, the mountain forces the air to rise, creating clouds, and the energy came from the large-scale flow.

For your other questions, yes, the same thermodynamic laws apply to them equally. For atmospheric things (both the lighting, wind turbine, and everything else), the source of energy is the sun, which is a massive source of energy. Again, if the earth is your system, these processes are not spontaneous because of this energy input. But if the sun + earth is your system, then these processes are spontaneous. If you take the universe as a whole, there are only spontaneous processes occurring. Keep in mind that overall, energy is conserved.

Comment: Thanks for the cloud example.  Those are the ones that are lens shaped, right?  This is pretty much the way I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if the term "spontaneous" only applies to situations where a Gibbs or Helmholtz free energy can be defined.  But it makes sense for it to apply more generally.

Comment: The lens shaped clouds, lenticulars, can form this way, and also others can. And even systems that are large, complex, or include intelligent beings can still have defined values for Gibbs and Helmholtz free energy.

Comment: Can you point me to this more general definition for free energy, or provide it here if it's not too much trouble?  I am used to thinking of quantities like U, T, and S as being defined at or near equilibrium, which would exclude living things for sure.  Thanks.

Comment: I’m sure the definitions are the same. My point is just that the thermodynamics still applies to an arbitrarily complex system. You might, for example, have a system where T is a function T(x,y,z) and so other thermodynamic quantities might need to be a function of space too and not just one value. So I’m just saying that, while calculations might be hard, the same laws of thermodynamics apply to all systems.